# AngularJS - Group objects in an array with a same value into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects that include a startDate. The objects are not in order of startDate. I want to create a new array and group all objects that share the same startDate into separate objects.

```
var eventArray = [
  {
    eventName: "event1",
    startDate: "2018/08/01", // YYYY/MM/DD
    id: 1
  },
  {
    eventName: "event2",
    startDate: "2018/08/03",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    eventName: "event3",
    startDate: "2018/08/01",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    eventName: "event4",
    startDate: "2018/08/06",
    id: 4
  }
];
```

Using angular.forEach I've tried looping through all the objects, getting the startDate value, adding that value to a new array, and adding the current object to the array where it has a matching date. I cannot find a solution to add the current event object to the object that exists in the new array (eventDays) at the index that matches my eventIndex variable.

```
let eventDays = [];
let eventIndex = 0;

angular.forEach(eventArray, function(event){
  let day = event.startDate;

  if(eventDays.length == 0){
    eventDays.push({
      dateGroup: day,
      event
    });
  }
  else {
    if(event.startDate == eventDays[eventIndex].groupDay) {
      // insert event object into eventDays[eventIndex] after dateGroup, event
    }
    else if(event.startDate !== eventDays[eventIndex].groupDay){
      eventDays.push({
        dateGroup: day,
        event
      });

      eventIndex++;
    }
  }

});
```

The result I'm looking for is something like this.

```
eventDays  = [
  {
    groupDate: "2018/08/01",
    event: {
      eventName: "event1",
      startDate: "2018/08/01",
      id: 1
    },
    event: {
      eventName: "event3",
      startDate: "2018/08/01",
      id: 3
    }
  },
  {
    groupDate: "2018/08/03",
    event: {
      eventName: "event2",
      startDate: "2018/08/03",
      id: 2
    }
  },
  {
    groupDate: "2018/08/06",
    event: {
      eventName: "event4",
      startDate: "2018/08/06",
      id: 4
    }
  }
];
```

Is something like this possible?

### UPDATE

Nina is right, I cannot reuse the name keyname. I need to create another array within the object to store the objects I'm passing over. This snippet is working.

```
angular.forEach($scope.events, function (event) {

            if ($scope.eventDays.length == 0) {
                $scope.eventDays.push({
                    'groupDate': event.startDate,
                    'events': [event]
                });
            } else {
                if (event.startDate == $scope.eventDays[eventIndex].groupDate) {
                    $scope.eventDays[eventIndex].events.push(event)
                } else if (event.startDate !== $scope.eventDays[eventIndex].groupDate) {
                    $scope.eventDays.push({
                        'groupDate': event.startDate,
                        'events': [event]
                    });

                    eventIndex++;
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: no, you can not have the same keyname twice. you could take an array for collecting the objects.

Comment: Nina is correct, it should be something like groupDate: '2018/08/03', events: [{eventName: "event1", startDate: "2018/08/01", id: 1},{eventName: "event3",startDate: "2018/08/01",id: 3}] then you can just change the way you get them slightly. It would be looping through events in an array instead of having top level objects. This is also a better way to format JSON data.

Comment: frostbyte, FYI, @NinaScholz refers to the keyname `event`. You have to think about any other output alternative. When you do so, update the question.

Comment: Nina it totally right. I'm ashamed I missed that. I've made an update to my post. I'm adding the current `event` to an `events` array. This is working!

Comment: If you have an answer for your question, don't add it to the question. Put it in the answer section. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer),

Comment: @georgeawg thanks for the heads up! I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for grouping the same `startDate` and render than the array with the objects.

```js
var eventArray = [{ eventName: "event1", startDate: "2018/08/01", id: 1 }, { eventName: "event2", startDate: "2018/08/03", id: 2 }, { eventName: "event3", startDate: "2018/08/01", id: 3 }, { eventName: "event4", startDate: "2018/08/06", id: 4 }],
    result = Array.from(
        eventArray.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.startDate, (m.get(o.startDate) || []).concat(o)), new Map),
        ([groupDate, events]) => ({ groupDate, events })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with using `Map` in JS. Your solution is a lot cleaner than mine. I'm going to play around with your solution and see if I can get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nina is right, I cannot reuse the name keyname. I need to create another array within the object to store the objects I'm passing over. This snippet is working.

```
angular.forEach($scope.events, function (event) {

        if ($scope.eventDays.length == 0) {
            $scope.eventDays.push({
                'groupDate': event.startDate,
                'events': [event]
            });
        } else {
            if (event.startDate == $scope.eventDays[eventIndex].groupDate) {
                $scope.eventDays[eventIndex].events.push(event)
            } else if (event.startDate !== $scope.eventDays[eventIndex].groupDate) {
                $scope.eventDays.push({
                    'groupDate': event.startDate,
                    'events': [event]
                });

                eventIndex++;
            }
        }

    });
```